# What is this type of insulation?

Tags: insulation, attic, asbestos

I just bought a house and I find this stuff in the loft. I'm worried it is asbestos... Is it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: With any "does it have asbestos" question, the only correct answer is "you have to have it tested by a lab" - you can't assume. You normally can't tell by casual examination, unless it has a brand-name imprinted (Transite® for pipes and sheets, for instance.) Some vermiculite (expanded mica insulation) has asbestos contamination from the deposit it was mined from, some does not. The basic material is not asbestos, but some deposits do have asbestos as a contaminant in the mica deposit.

Comment: If it is not asbestos, the alternatives still have bad dust. Wear breathing mask.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Vermiculite is a hydrous phyllosilicate mineral which undergoes significant expansion when heated. Exfoliation occurs when the mineral is heated sufficiently, and commercial furnaces can routinely produce this effect. Vermiculite forms by the weathering or hydrothermal alteration of biotite or phlogopite. Large commercial vermiculite mines currently exist in the United States of America, Russia, South Africa, China, and Brazil.

> As loose-fill insulation: Exfoliated vermiculite treated with a water repellent is used to fill the pores and cavities of masonry construction and hollow blockwork to enhance fire ratings (e.g. Underwriters Laboratories Wall and Partition designs), thermal insulation, and acoustic performance. Expanded vermiculite has also been used as thermal insulation in the attics and walls of houses and in water heaters, fire safes, stoves, furnaces, and refrigerators.

> Although not all vermiculite contains asbestos, some products were made with vermiculite that contained asbestos until the early 1990s. Vermiculite mines throughout the world are now regularly tested for it and are supposed to sell products that contain no asbestos. The former vermiculite mine in Libby, Montana, did have tremolite asbestos as well as winchite and richterite (both fibrous amphiboles)—in fact, it was formed underground through essentially the same geologic processes as the contaminants.
>
> Pure vermiculite does not contain asbestos and is non-toxic. Impure vermiculite may contain, apart from asbestos, also minor diopside or remnants of the precursor minerals biotite or phlogopite.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vermiculite

I would have a sample tested by a lab, then I'd overlay blown cellulose to bring your attic to modern insulation standards, along with upgrading ventilation if necessary.

Comment: Agree, but would keep in mind that ceilings (well, the holes in the ceiling) are porous, so removal (assuming positive test) might be prudent.

Comment: That was implied. There's no point in testing if no action will be taken upon a positive result. :)

Comment: If there is asbestos associated with the vermiculite (as proven by a test of the OPs sample, not rampant speculation), what is the likelihood of any of it being free-form and floating through the air. i.e., is it really _necessary_ to remove it? The only danger from asbestos is breathing in particles, and if the asbestos is intertwined with the vermiculite, then it's likely not going anywhere _until_ it's disturbed (by removal).

Comment: @FreeMan You can never know if it will be disturbed in the future or was disturbed in the past. For al I know the previous home-owner disturbed the stuff seriously just a week before he sold the house. Better safe than sorry. Besides that: In many places local building codes mandate asbestos removal if you know it is there. It is also a point if you ever going to sell the house: If the next owner finds out there is asbestos and you didn't warn them upfront they might sue you for misrepresenting the house in the sale. Depending on your jurisdiction that could get real ugly with court-cases.

Comment: Given the house sale was recent, the removal cost can go back to the previous owner if it actually is asbestos.

Comment: Better just seal up the house and walk away if its asbestos right?  I mean there's no room for nuance or practicality is there?

Comment: No. Asbestos can be mitigated safely. It's not phosgene gas. :)